# Exercise 1-3-16 Kaplanski

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want answer this exersice,

> Let $R\subset T$ be rings with $R$ a Hilbert ring and $T$ finitely generated as a ring over $R$. Prove that any maximal ideal in $T$ contracts to a maximal ideal in $R$.

Please help me to find answer.

Comment: You prove that $R/M^c$ embeds into $T/M$, but this alone won't prove that $M^c$ is maximal as there are a lot of (non-field) rings that embed into fields. To make use of the hypotheses you can prove that $M^c$ is a $G$-ideal (e.g. using exercise 1 and Thm 22)

Answer (score 0):

We prove this by induction on elements generated $T$. In this way:

$T$ is finitely generated over $R$, so,
$$\exists\, \, c_1,\ldots , c_n \in T\, \, \, s.t \, \, \, T=R[c_1,\ldots , c_n].$$
First suppose $n=1$, then $T=R[c]$. If $M$ be a maximal in $T$ then, $T/M$ is field and $$R/(M\cap R)\cong \varphi(R)$$ is a domain such that $\varphi$ is natrual homomorphism from $R$ to $T$.

By, isomorphism,
$$\psi: T/M \longrightarrow \varphi(R)[c+M]$$
suth that,
$\psi(\sum r_i c^i + M)= \sum (r_i + M)(c+M)^i$
we conclude $\varphi(R)[c+M]$ is a field and so is G-domain. Then, by using theorem 23, we can conclude that $\varphi(R)$ is G-domain. So $R/(M\cap R)$ is G-domain and $M\cap R$ is G-ideal. Finitly, $R\cap M$ is maximal  because $R$ is hilbert. The remain of proof, is so simple and immediate obtained.